# Ruby: code "updgrading" from 1.8.6 to 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2

i'm interested in updating code which is written in ruby v`1.8.6` to `1.9.2`.
 Are there any useful links to read about (probably with some warnings and recommendations)?

Just to be clear, so, i'm not expecting any problems right now, but i would like to avoid them.

P.S.
Links like this [one](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21016488-migrate-to-ruby-1-9-2) are mostly not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slideshow showing the differences:  http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/ruby19.html#11
I migrated an app from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 a few days ago, and no problems happened.
Bu i advise you to test all of your code for little bugs.

Comment: +1 for slideshow link. Definitely a good thing to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that all the gems you depend on are 1.9.2 compatible.  [isitruby19.com](http://isitruby19.com/) is a good resource to check this.

Other than that, the best strategy is to try migrating and do some testing.  If your application has comprehensive unit test coverage, this shouldn't be too painful.